# asp.net website deployment in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

I have a very simple website which displays Hello World. I tried to deploy this project on the server. These are the steps I followed:

1. Copy the folder of the project to inetpub/wwwroot folder.
2. In IIS management, created a website. Gave the path of the website from step 1.
3. Gave the application pool as .NET 3.5

After doing the above, while browsing the page, I received the error- Type not found in web.config.

Comment: Without more information to go on (i.e. the contents of the error page when viewed in the server's browser) it's not easy to say. However, it's possible that the server is missing a component that you have on your development machine. If you were using an older version of .NET I'd suggest the AJAX extensions

Comment: Did it give you a line number for the web.config error? Can you copy and paste the error, and a snippet of your web.config?

Comment: How do you set an application pool to run as .NET 3.5? That is a kewl trick . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if you can browse a simple image there.  that is, copy a jpg to the root of your web site and try to open it.

paste your web.config, that would be a help.

(app pool is set from advanced options in inetmgr program)

Comment: Thanks all. The problem got resolved. I had not set the version in ASP.NET tab to 2.0. After setting it, it worked. In the same context,when I use Microsoft Interop Excel ddl, I am getting the following error Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154.

On searching in google, I didn't find a proper answer. I basically want to use this DDL to create excel file with pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

Add all website(or application.exe) files to the IIS Virtual Directory instead of wwwrootfolder. (IIS virutal directory is created by you while configuring IIS server)

**Or**

- New Website
- Under Locations Click on "Browse"
- Click on "Local IIS" and then select the "IIS Virtual Directory"(IIS vitual Directory which is directory created by the user while configuring IIS server)
- Open manually using Explorer drag and
- add all you files to the "solution explorer"
- then "Yes to all"